# How simplify calling include with multiple viariables in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to simplify (make more readable) Django template code:

```
{% comment %}
required variables:
group_id = 'exclude-brands-group'
select_name = 'exclude-brands'
entities = 'excludeBrandsSets'
add_keyword_name = {% trans 'Brand' %}
url_edit_keywords = {{ url_project_filter_exclude_brands_edit_keywords }}
{% endcomment %}

{% with group_id='exclude-keywords-group' select_name='exclude-keywords' %}
{% with entities=excludeKeywordsSets %}
{% trans 'Words' as add_keyword_name %}
{% with url_edit_keywords=url_project_filter_exclude_keywords %}
{% include 'web_site/seo/frontend/seo/filtered_keyword_idea/template/keyword_filter_group.html' %}
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

But I do not have idea how to reduce number of **with** tags - since **include** is only one line command. I have not idea how simplify trans. Do you know some simpler way to pass variables to templates?

Answer (score 3):

The [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include) lets you pass additional context to the template. That means you don't need separate with tags (although the downside is you end up with very long lines). There isn't any way to include the trans tag.

```
{% trans 'Words' as add_keyword_name %}
{% include 'web_site/seo/frontend/seo/filtered_keyword_idea/template/keyword_filter_group.html' with group_id='exclude-keywords-group' select_name='exclude-keywords' entities=excludeKeywordsSets url_edit_keywords=url_project_filter_exclude_keywords %}
```

Comment: If I need to use a template tag with `with` (and have a few of those), guessing I'll still need the `with` tags, like: `{% with template_tag arg1 arg2 as final_val1 %} {% with template_tag arg2 arg3 as final_val2 %} {%include ....val1=final_val1 val2=final_val2`%}

Comment: Edit: I figured that simple tags dont need with for assignments, so I mean the following in the above comment: `{% template_tag arg1 arg2 as final_val1 %} {% template_tag arg2 arg3 as final_val2 %} {%include ....val1=final_val1 val2=final_val2%}`